# Reduce time of computing partial derivatives

Tags: python, derivative

I am computing the first and second order partial derivatives of a function (using numdifftools) with three unknown values to find values where my function has a minimum. This is the code:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

def partial_function(f___,input,pos,value):
    tmp  = input[pos]
    input[pos] = value
    ret = f___(*input)
    input[pos] = tmp
    return ret

def derivative(f,input):
    # f - function I want to derive
    # input - points where I want to calculate the derivative
    first = np.empty(len(input))
    second = np.empty(len(input))
    for i in range(len(input)):
        fg = lambda x:partial_function(f,input,i,x)
        first[i] = nd.Derivative(fg)(input[i])                 #first deriv
        second[i] = nd.Derivative(nd.Derivative(fg))(input[i]) #second deriv
    deriv = np.vstack((first,second))
    return deriv
```

The function I want to minimize is something like this:

```
func = lambda w,m,s: sum((gamma_[k,:]-w*gaussian(x,m,s))**2)
```

Where `gamma_[k,:]` is a known vector.

I call the derivative method like this:

`d = derivative(func,param0)`

where `param0` are the initial guesses (a 1x3 vector in this case)

The problem is that I run the optimization algorithm several times and time per iteration is huge, due to the derivate computation. Which approach can I take in order to reduce the time to compute these derivatives?

Comment: I think `second[i] = nd.Derivative(nd.Derivative(fg))(input[i])` should be second[i] = nd.Derivative(fg, n=2)(input[i]) #second deriv

Comment: @RootTwo yes, that was the problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RootTwo it is still slow: 300 iterations of my optimization algorithm takes about 20 seconds, but with the finite differences approach of my answer it takes less than 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed my own functions for derivatives using finite differences:

```
def firstDerivative(f, param):
    h = 1e-5
    deriv = np.zeros(len(param))
    for i in range(len(param)):
        rise = np.copy(param)
        rise[i] = rise[i] + h
        deriv[i] = (f(rise) - f(param))/h
    return deriv
```

In this function, `f` is the expression which I calculate the derivative and `param` are the values.
These functions perform much better than the functions I used in my question. For the second derivative is pretty much the same, just check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference